# Spark task fails continuously with Error communicating with MapOutputTracker

Tags: apache-spark

After spark application run for a period of time on spark 3.2.1 the tasks started to fail continuously even after restarting the application with files of maximum size (1-2 Mb)

Driver Stacktrace:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 536.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 536.0 (TID 694) (10.183.126.83 executor 0): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Error communicating with MapOutputTracker
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.askTracker(MapOutputTracker.scala:498)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerWorker.$anonfun$getStatuses$7(MapOutputTracker.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.util.KeyLock.withLock(KeyLock.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerWorker.getStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerWorker.getMapSizesByExecutorIdImpl(MapOutputTracker.scala:1222)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerWorker.getMapSizesByExecutorId(MapOutputTracker.scala:1192)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleManager.getReader(SortShuffleManager.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleManager.getReader(ShuffleManager.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleManager.getReader$(ShuffleManager.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleManager.getReader(SortShuffleManager.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ShuffledRowRDD.compute(ShuffledRowRDD.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecutionRDD.compute(SQLExecutionRDD.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:58)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(RpcEndpointRef.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(RpcEndpointRef.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.askTracker(MapOutputTracker.scala:494)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:259)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    ... 38 more
```

I tried to tune spark.rpc.askTimeout config with bigger value but with no luck the error still taking place even with different values of sql suffle partitions (50 & 200)

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there are too many map output files after shuffle write operation. You can decrease this number by increasing partitions size spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes.